# Android-Twitter Twitter4j dialoge "Sign Up" link not working

Tags: android, api, twitter, twitter4j

I have an app that basically allows you to tweet,
After logging in via the twitter4j dialoge you can go ahead and proceed to tweet via the application etc.

The problem is, when the dialoge appears showing the twitter website to logging in, the link "sign up" or "forgot password" doest work....

Ive searched around but cannot find any explination?

If any code is requires please ask,
Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more explanation as to "not working"? Does it show a page not found? In any case something may be generically wrong with oAuth. A similar question was posted an hour after yours, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974568/problems-by-twitter-authorization-via-jsoauth-oauth

Comment: it doesnt do anything.... thats the thing,
you click the sign up link and it highlight and nothing happens, as if it was just a blank link...

Ive searched everywhere for this but nowhere seems to have such problems.

Comment: yeah, this may be a Java specific issue then which i don't know much about :\ GL.